# How to build a JS module that can be used on the page directly?

Tags: javascript, umd

I am the author of [vue-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sequence). This library is built with vue-cli and it export a library in `umd` format. To use this library, I have to use webpack to make it work on a web page, something like:

```
import { SeqDiagram, Store } from "vue-sequence";
...
Vue.use(vuex);
Vue.component("seq-diagram", SeqDiagram);
let store = new vuex.Store(Store);
```

A complete example of using it can be found at here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v4v78w1wk.

I would like to be able to use it directly on a page (but still support using it as a node module), like:

```html
<script src="vue-sequence.js" />

<script>
vueSequence.processAll()
</script>
```

I understand I would need to define this `processAll()` method somewhere. My question is about how to package this library.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things. I think I know how `umd` works better. If we directly include the `umd` library on a web page, the library will create a field on the global `window` variable (in this case `vue-sequence` and referable via window['vue-sequence']).

With the following html configuration

```html
<title>vue-sequence demo</title>
<script src="./vue-sequence.umd.js"></script>

<script>
console.log(window['vue-sequence'])
</script>
```

It will print out the exported module. Knowing about this is enough for me to continue working on a solution to add the `processAll()` fuction.